# Filling in cell color by cell contents

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

I'm writing an automation script containing an excel sheet that marks down whether a cell is passed/failed/untested. I was wondering whether there would be a method for xlsx to detect which cells have the text of pass/fail in them and set the color accordingly.

What I have in mind, in psudeocode:

```
Sheet1.write("B2", "Passed")
Sheet1.write("B3", "Failed")
Sheet1.write("B4", "Untested")

if cell_contains "Passed"
   cell_format.set_bg_color('green')
elif cell_contains "Failed"
   cell_format.set_bg_color('red')
else
   pass
```

Comment: Normally one would do this in Excel using conditional formatting rules.  So why don't you build 2 conditional rules on your entire data range as explained here: https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/conditional-formatting/

Comment: This can be done without any VBA via Conditional Formatting in the Home Tab of the Ribbon in Excel. Just set the rule so if = "Passed" then set the color and do this for each condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
    If Range("B2").Value = "Passed" Then
       Range("B2").Interior.Color = RGB(1, 1, 1)
    End If
```

I would suggest not open a thread in StackOverflow, cause you can find a lot of documentation for such easy things over the internet